# Question on Excel document level deployment

Tags: excel, deployment, vsto

We have a VSTO excel document level project. The excel document created as part of this project has a worksheet (named Start Sheet) which has some winforms controls (like button, checkbox etc) and there are many other worksheets which mainly contains data. We
deploy this solution using Windows Installer to client’s machines. The excel version is excel 2007 and VSTO 2010.

Whenever our solution is deployed on client’s machines, the clients usually customize the excel document on their machine. Like they will add some new worksheets apart from the ones we have added. They also install some addins like PI to bring in data to these worksheets. Now we usually have enhancement request from our clients and most of these enhancements 
are adding new sheets to the excel document. Almost 99% of the requests are adding a new sheet. The code behind each sheet is some business logic which is mainly triggered by the winform controls on Start sheet.

Now every time, they install a enhanced version of the solution, they end up getting a new excel document and then they have to customize it again (like adding some sheets, writing macros etc), which is lot of work for them. This is a huge problem for us these days
as our clients do not like it at all.

Is there a way that they can deploy the new versions of solution and still keep their excel document customizations unchanged ? My experience with VSTO is not much and help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your vsto doc-level assembly get added to the GAC, or does it get accessed by Excel via manifests (sxs)? If the doc-level assembly is deployed side-by-side with the xlsx, can't your installer just push out a new .vsto, myassembly.dll.manifest, and myassembly.dll into the target directory?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the design of the project so that the code and template elements (sheets, formatting, formulae, controls, encapsulated data etc) are separated from the users excel documents but can generate or modify the users documents. The EUI would be Excel Menus/Toolbars or Ribbon Tabs.
Usually you would do this by creating an Excel Addin (XLA, XLL, COM or Automation Addin).

Comment: Hello Charles, Thanks a lot for your reply. However, if we change the design to Excel Addin type project, then when they install it, then each instance of excel they launch will have the functionality (like worksheets or UI controls etc) that we have put in. Wouldn't it ?

Comment: The worksheets etc are all hidden in the Addin. You just expose a top-level Menu which has drop-down commands for things like: Create New Special Workbook, Add Sheet TypeA etc. You could get cleverer if you want by having the addin start with just a Create Special Workbook Command, but dynamically recognise when the user opens your special type of workbook (use a hidden name), and then dynamically add more menu commands. The other advantage of this approach is that you can easily update the addin.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have an upgrade routine that during installation copies their old document, replaces it with the new, and then traverses the old copy for new sheets and what not to bring over.